# How to speed up build for large translation files in Meteor and tapi18n?

Tags: meteor, build, localization, meteor-blaze

Our project has grown and the build has slowed to a crawl. I recently profiled it to see over a minute processing the i18n files for localization.

We have 2200 lines in each language file and 13 languages. A minute to build wouldn't be an issue except that locally when developing the rebuild for any change also compiles those files.

Is there some way to move the files to a package or structure the files to be more efficient? Most people who complain about the rebuild time are mad about 20 seconds which we would be thrilled to see at this point.

Comment: In which folder are the files located inside your project? Which Meteor version are you running on?

Comment: Currently we are on Meteor 1.6.1.3 although I did an experiment upgrading to 1.8.0.1 to see if anything had improved and it stayed the same.  We keep the i18 files in the \both\tap-i18n folder

Comment: I see. Another option you could try is to move all i18n related assets into a local Meteor package and add them using `api.addAssets` which may cause the bundler to mark them as assets and ignore them when parsing. Just an idea. https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html#PackageAPI-addAssets

Comment: Because of where tapi18n wants the files, I assume they are compiling the json into js (and because it spends time compiling). If they were added in assets that would likely bypass that process entirely leaving no translated strings.  I did try moving them into a local package with the files added as normal code files but they were never available to the app.